# What exactly is a navigablestring (HTML)?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to scrape text from webpages using Python 2.7's BeautifulSoup (bs4). My original code is as follows:

```
string = ''
a = soup.find('div',attrs={"id":"pressrelease"})
[x.extract() for x in a.findAll('script')]
[x.extract() for x in a.findAll("span", {'class':'hidden'})]
    
for element in a:
     try:
         string += element.get_text()
        
     except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Although my code does get me the desired text, it also spits out the following error: **'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'**. I want to implement a feature that saves the URL if the code hits an exception but in this case, I don't want the URL saved since even though it's throwing an exception the page was successfully scraped. Thus, I am trying to better understand what the error exactly is (so I can decide whether to purposefully ignore this case).

Any explanations on what a navigablestring is and why it would cause my code to throw such an error would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Reading the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) is the only true way of learning how to use a package. A lot of effort was invested in writing it. There are no simple answers to complex questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `NavigableString` is a bit of text in your HTML document. See [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring). At least one of the items inside the tag you searched for is a bit of text, probably some white space.

Strings can't contain text, they *are* text, so they don't have a `get_text` method, and therefore it is an error to try to call such a method.

You can check each item to see if it's a `bs4.element.Tag` before trying to call `get_text()` on them.

```
for item in a:
     if type(item) is bs4.element.Tag:
         string += item.get_text()
```

Note I changed your iteration variable to `item` since the fact that you called it `element` has probably fixated you on the idea that it is, in fact, an HTML element, when in at least one case it's definitely not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did the following print statement:

`if isinstance(x, element.NavigableString):
        print x`

And it looks like the NavigableString were indeed whitespace but also two comments. Just curious, where exactly is this white space coming from? And would it be reasonable to assume that if we wanted to scrape text from any webpage, we can safely ignore any element.NavigableStrings?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add: in response to your question, the div that I searched for contains a lot of children and their children.

Comment: Iterating over a tag (like with a `for` loop) is going to give you every item inside that tag, which will include other tags, text, and comments. Actually there's no bug here, I had just forgotten that iterating over a tag yields all its elements (maybe I had misread your question and thought you were using `findall` rather than `find`). You might just want `a.get_text()` rather than a `for` loop?

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I wasn't doing that in the first place haha... Thank you so much for your help!